# FAL saving image in backend module does not set the uid_local

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a backend module that does some data transfer from an old 'profile' database to TYPO3.
For the images, I first renamed them and placed them in a storage. 
The records of the profiles also have been copied and are stored in the DB.

I then get the file information of each file that is in the storage for a profile

```
$file = $storage->getFile($filetoget['filename']);
```

and gives me just what i need.

I then create a new file reference object:

```
$profilemedia =  $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\Regprofiler\Domain\Model\FileReference');
```

I can add all properties to this object that i need.
I also set:

```
$profilemedia->setUidLocal($fileProps['uid']);
```

when I then add the image to my profile and update my profile repository, all file refrences get stored as expected, EXCEPT the uid_local, this stays 0
what is annoying, because this way I don't get a reference to the sys_file and therefore: no image.

So why don't I get the uid_local stored ?

my TCA for the image

```
'image' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'image',
            'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'inline',
                'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_regprofiler_domain_model_profiler',
                'foreign_field' => 'parent',
                'size' => 5,
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 99,
                'appearance' => array(
                    'collapseAll' => 1,
                    'expandSingle' => 1,
                    'levelLinksPosition' => 'bottom',
                    'useSortable' => 1,
                    'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                    'showRemovedLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                    'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1,
                    'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                    'enabledControls' => array(
                        'info' => FALSE,
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, before creating a module to generate your data, that you can create the database-records using the TYPO3-Backend. Simply add a record and check if you can add an Image there. If it appears, you have an error in your module, else you have an error in your TCA.

It is also recommended using

```php
$TCA['tx_yourext_domain_model_yourmodel']['columns']['image']['config'] =
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('yourImageFieldHere',
    array(
        'maxitems' => 1,
        'appearance' => array(
            'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:nwb_page_tools/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_customlabels.xlf:add_image'
        )
    ),
    'jpg,png'
);
```

in your TCA definition. This is a core method wich can be reviewed [here](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html#ab95ff2f805d3ec462e869057339eee04)

Comment: Tnx Merdec,

I did shnegd the TCA, but this seems not to solve it.